# Is pinia StoreToRefs() more efficient than loading the whole store?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

If a component needs the data and 1 of the multiple actions in a pinia store,
Is *this*:

```
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { useMyStore } from './myStore';
const myStore = useMyStore();
const { data, oneActionOfMany } = storeToRefs(myStore);

oneActionOfMany ();
```

Better than ***this*** for any reason?

````
import { useMyStore } from './myStore';
const myStore = useMyStore();
myStore.oneActionOfMany ();```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's litteraly the same performance since `storeToRefs` is skipping non-reactivate property into the process, such as actions.

So whether you call your action from `store.oneActionOfMany` or from destructuring `storeToRefs()`, it's the same function reference.

In the end, just use `storeToRefs()` to destructure reactive data if needed, not actions, as it's useless to do so.

From the pinia [documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Destructuring-from-a-Store):

```
// This will also extract refs for properties added by plugins
// but *skip any action or non reactive (non ref/reactive) property*
const { name, doubleCount } = storeToRefs(store)
// the increment action can just be destructured
const { increment } = store
```

Comment: "it's the same function reference" - this is imprecise, storeToRefs returns refs only, as the name suggests https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/blob/v2/packages/pinia/src/storeToRefs.ts#L51-L61 , code from the OP would fail